# What would a Big O(sqrt(3)^n) Algorithm look like?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm working through some exercises in chapter 10 of Kleinberg and Tardos, and one problem asks for me to give an algorithm for 3-SAT with a O(sqrt(3)^n) running time. I don't really know what an algorithm that run time would look like, let alone how to construct such an algorithm.

Comment: That is essentially `O(3^(n/2))`.  You can devise such an algorithm by doing a linear search through all sequences of 0, 1, and 2 of length n/2.  Whether that has anything to do with 3-SAT, I don't know.  But that is what such an algorithm would look like.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks.